# Mongoexport shell script - Error in query

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I wrote a shell script to create a data dump of records updated yesterday using mongoexport command.

```
yesterday=$(date -d 'yesterday 00:00:00' '+%s'000)
today=$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' '+%s'000)
query="'{\"updated_at\":{\$gte:new Date(${yesterday}),\$lte:new Date(${today})}}'"
echo ${query}

mongoexport -h $HOST -d $DOC -c $COL_NAME -u $USER -p $PWD -q ${query} -o $fileName
```

After adding query, when I run the shell script I get below error in console

```
'{"updated_at":{$gte:new Date(1484287200000),$lte:new Date(1484373600000)}}'
too many positional arguments: [Date(1484287200000),$lte:new Date(1484373600000)}}']
try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

When I run this query in command line it works properly. Can someone pls let me know why is this error when ran in shell script?

This works in command line.

```
$mongoexport -h <<HOST>> -d <<DOC>> -c <<COL> -u <<UN>> -p <<PWD>> -q '{"updated_at":{"$gte":new Date(1484287200000),"$lte":new Date(1484373600000)}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule of thumb in `bash`: when you use a variable, always surround it with double quotes. There are exceptions, but they are rare.

```
mongoexport -h "$HOST" -d "$DOC" -c "$COL_NAME" -u "$USER" -p "$PWD" -q "${query}" -o "$fileName"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I tried in shell script with double quotes, I get below error. `'{"updated_at":{$gte:new Date(1484287200000),$lte:new Date(1484373600000)}}'
2017-01-14T18:02:22.557-0600 error validating settings: query '[39 123 34 117 112 100 97 116 101 100 95 97 116 34 58 123 36 103 116 101 58 110 101 119 32 68 97 116 101 40 49 52 56 52 50 56 55 50 48 48 48 48 48 41 44 36 108 116 101 58 110 101 119 32 68 97 116 101 40 49 52 56 52 51 55 51 54 48 48 48 48 48 41 125 125 39]' is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}`

Comment: @user1637487 I don't know mongo but I believe the surrounding single quotes, in your definition of `query` should be remove. Keep only the double quotes: `query="{...}"`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
yesterday=$(date -d 'yesterday 00:00:00' '+%s'000)
today=$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' '+%s'000)
query1="{\"transactionDate\":{\$gte: new Date(${yesterday}),\$lte: new Date(${today})}}"
echo $yesterday
echo $today

mongoexport -d databasename-c collectionname --host yourip --port 27017 -p password -u username-q "${query1}" --type=csv --fields=transactionDate,amount > test5.csv
```